# Query over throws exception

Tags: c#, queryover

I tried this query over criteria:

```
Area area = null
var res = session.QueryOver<Area>(() => area);

res.UnderlyingCriteria.Add(Expression.Where<Area>(x => x.shops.where(s => s.Id == 40503) != null));
```

And it throw me this exception:

> "Variable x of type Area referenced from scope, but it is not defined"

Someone know why it happen?

Comment: I wrote there not null. I wanted to return area that contains shop with id 40503 (the id is example)

Comment: I already tried this. It throw me the same exception i know the problem is in the underlying criteria because if i change it a bit it work (but not check what i search)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using your `area` alias?

```
res.UnderlyingCriteria.Add(Expression.Where<Area>(() => area.shops.where(s => s.Id == 40503) != null));
```

Even that seems over complicated. This would be better:

```
Area area = null;
Shop shop = null
var res = session.QueryOver<Area>(() => area)
.Left.JoinAlias(() => area.shops, () => shop)
.Where(() => shop.Id == 40503);
```